# Simple Dom Parser issues with the latest php version

Tags: php

For a while I've been using Simple DOM Parser to extract some information from websites, but lately it doesn't work for me, for example, I can't parser from this website which is by the way a wordpress site:

```
include_once("simplehtmldom/simple_html_dom.php");
$pageUrl = "http://abstellgenehmigung.com/";
$html = file_get_html($pageUrl);
if(!empty($html)){
    if(!empty($html->find("a"))){
        foreach($html->find("a") as $a){
           echo($a->getAttribute('href') .'<br> ');
         }
       }
    }
```

Do you guys know how to solve this problem, or do you know other alternative to simple dom parser ?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does the url http://abstellgenehmigung.com give you the expected result?

Comment: It gives nothing just Null

Comment: When you load the url, which "a" do you expect to find?

Comment: It's just for testing I want to target the form elements

Answer (score 0):

I had a problem with the `file_get_html` function of Simple HTML5 Dom Parser and PHP 7 (or more precisely, PHP 7.1).

**Note: I've juste noticed that the bug has been corrected yesterday, so this problem should not appear in the latest versions (https://sourceforge.net/p/simplehtmldom/repository/ci/3ab5ee865e460c56859f5a80d74727335f4516de/**)

Workaround : replace

```
$html = file_get_html('websiteURL');

(which is equivalent to)

$html = file_get_html('websiteURL', false, null, -1);
```

by

```
$html = file_get_html('websiteURL', false, null, 0);
```

Explanation: The PHP function '[file_get_contents](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php)' changed for PHP 7.1 (support for negative offsets has been added), so the '-1' value used by Simple HTML5 Dom Parser is invalid for PHP>=7.1.